# Why is the beginning of a C file stream called `SEEK_SET`?

Tags: c, file, io

There are three `origin` constants you can use in functions like `fseek` to determine from where your `offset` is counted: `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, and `SEEK_END`. `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_END` seem self-explanatory to mean the current position and end of the file stream, but why is `SEEK_SET` used to mean the beginning? Why not something like `SEEK_BEG`?

Comment: No, it means "set to the specified position". Which may be or not be the beginning of the stream.

Comment: The stream implementation uses an offset to manage its position within the file. The offset is measured from the beginning of the file. `SEEK_SET` sets the offset (notionally `offset = value`). `SEEK_CUR` adjusts the offset relative to its current value (notionally `offset += value`). `SEEK_END` adjusts the offset relative to the end (notionally `offset = end + value`). Thus, `SEEK_SET` is `SEEK_BEG` because the offset is measured from the beginning of the file; the beginning of the file and offset 0 are the same, so `offset = value` is the same as `offset = beginning + value`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you can add an offset. By using `SEEK_SET`, you can explicitly set an offset. (By adding it to the beginning)

From the manpage of fseek:

```
The new position, measured in bytes, is
obtained by adding offset bytes to the position specified by whence.
If whence is set to SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END, the offset is
relative to the start of the file, the current position indicator, or
end-of-file, respectively.
```

From the manpage of lseek:

```
   SEEK_SET
          The file offset is set to offset bytes.

   SEEK_CUR
          The file offset is set to its current location plus offset
          bytes.

   SEEK_END
          The file offset is set to the size of the file plus offset
          bytes.
```

Comment: ... that is, with `SEEK_SET`, the file position is *set* to exactly the value specified.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense. When `origin` is the beginning of the file, you are just `set`ting position with your offset.

Comment: I guess I could continue arguing that this doesn't 100% answer the question, as there's still no clear reasoning that `SEEK_SET` alone breaks the "grammar" of the other two options for `origin` (or `whence`). `SEEK_CUR` and `SEEK_END` explicitly state where your offset is applied, but `SEEK_SET` does not. Though I don't know if there is documentation on that naming choice.

Comment: I think, because setting it to a value is more intuitive to understand. "Set" is one (mental) operation, but add to the beginning is more operations. Following the naming pattern, SEEK_ADD_CUR would have been possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to the question as stated is "Because `fseek` has a second argument which isn't always zero".

***If*** you always passed the second argument as zero, then `SEEK_CUR` would set the file pointer to its current position (which would be a nearly useless no-op), and `SEEK_END` would set the file pointer to the end of file, and `SEEK_CUR` would set it to the beginning of the file, which might make you wonder why it wasn't called `SEEK_BEG`.

But of course `fseek` does have that second argument, and you usually pass it as an interesting, non-zero offset.  Much of the time, the second argument is the absolute offset you want to seek to, which is what `SEEK_SET` means.  As a convenience, you can also set a position plus-or-minus the current position, which is what `SEEK_CUR` is for, or plus-or-minus the end of the file, which is what `SEEK_END` is for.

In the case that `whence` is `SEEK_SET` and the offset *is* 0, meaning that you're trying to set the file pointer to the beginning of the file, there maybe ought to be a convenient shortcut for that, too.  But the shortcut isn't called `SEEK_BEG`, it's a completely different library function: `rewind(fp)`, which is indeed a shortcut for `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually have found that I often use `fseek` more with `SEEK_CUR` than with `SEEK_SET`, so in my particular experience it seems like the odd one out. But maybe this isn't the usual usage. I knew about `rewind`, though I never thought through that it would simply be a synonym for `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)`; that makes sense.